# Oops! Incorrect CiviCRM version. This installer can only be used for the Drupal version of CiviCRM

Tags: installation, backdrop

I get this message after (successfully) installing 5.4.0 into Backdrop 1.10.1. The download file is civicrm-5.4.0-backdrop.tar.gz and when I start to install it shows the correct version (it says Backdrop) in the upper right of the installer. The install completes okay. Any ideas?

Comment: I recently got this when i was trying to install drupal and it said 'This installer can only be used for the Backdrop version of CiviCRM'. Clearing up Drupal and CiviCRM caches fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you, Pradeep. I have cleared the Backdrop cache and cleared out the files/civicrm/templates_c directory. That did not resolve the problem. Is that how you cleared the cache?

Comment: That should be enough to clear the caches. There is also a url http://your-site.com/civicrm/clearcache?reset=1 which is use a lot.

Comment: I am getting this message trying to install civicrm 5.18.1 in Backdrop CMS 1.14.0 (fresh install, mamp). Not even getting to environment check for civi install. This pops up after entering install url command after downloading and creating civicrm folder in Backdrop modules folder.